# AudioKit v5, cannot find type 'SampleDescriptor' in scope

Tags: swift, audiokit, swift-package-manager

I try to create a sampler with SampleDescriptor. It seems Xcode 12.2 can't link the AudioKit header. I Implemented Audiokit with Swift Package Manager.

Answer (score 1):

*`import CAudioKit`* solved the issue.