# AudioKit - Cannot find 'Oscillator' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, audiokit

I have an iOS project in Xcode (SwiftUI interface and Swift language), for which I want to use the AudioKit Oscillator function. I have added the package dependencies for AudioKit 5.6.1 but I always get an error message behind the line `let oscillator = Oscillator(waveform: Table(.sine))` in my ContentView.swift that says `Cannot find 'Oscillator' in scope` and the project build fails.

[image: Screenshot of my example code line that includes the 'Oscillator' function]

Not sure if it's relevant but I am using Xcode 15.0 on an Intel Macbook Pro with MacOS Ventura (13.6).

I have tried different Xcode versions (15.0 / 14.3.1), as well as different AudioKit versions (5.6.1 / 5.3.3 / 5.0). The AudioKit packages, I have installed via Cocoapods as well as with the package manager in xcode, every time with the same result.

I saw that [someone else had a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66197294/audiokit-v5-cannot-find-type-sampledescriptor-in-scope), not finding another function in AudioKit 5 and they used `import CAudioKit` instead of `import AudioKit`. However, when I try this, I get another error that says `No such module 'CAudioKit'`

I have spent multiple hours already trying to resolve this and to find reports about similar issues but I think it's time for my first post here. It would be great if anyone could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oscillator you are searching for is a class in AudioKit's extension framework [SoundpipeAudioKit](https://www.audiokit.io/SoundpipeAudioKit).

You will need to add that package dependency to your project and then add `import SoundpipeAudioKit` in the `ContentView` file.